# Visual Studio игнорирует gets_s

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, поток-ввода

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с проблемой, когда нужно из консоли записать в буфер, используя gets_s(buf,size) или fgets(buf,size,/*поток*/), но Visual Studio просто пропускала их и ничего не считывала? Если подряд поставить два gets_s, то работает. Как считать строку с пробелами? Язык Си.
В строке функции editStr:
gets_s(buf, LINE);
Код программы:

```
static void editInt(int *num) {
    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);
    fflush(stdin);
    *num = value;
}
static void editStr(char *line) { 
    char buf[50];
    fflush(stdin);
    gets_s(buf, LINE);
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
    strcpy(line, buf);
}

void editingList(List **list) {
    printf("\nWould you like to edit list?\n"); 
    int num,fl;
    if (char c = _getch() == 'y') {
        printf("\nEnter surname of the element you want to edit: \n");
        char buf[20];
        scanf("%s", buf);
        fflush(stdin);
        Human *temp = (*list)->first;
        while (temp) {
            if (!strcmp(temp->surname, buf)) {
                while(1){
                    printf("\nWhich parameter would you like to change?\n");
                    printf("\n(1)Surname\n(2)Name\n(3)Patronymic\n(4)Gender\n(5)Birthday\n(6)Month of birthday\n(7)Year of birthday\n(8)Height\n(9)Weight\n(10)City\n(11)Interests\n(12)Bad habits\n(13)Personal text\n(14)Min preferred age\n(15)Max preferred age\n(16)Preferred bad habbits\n Press other button to return to menu\n");
                    int decision;
                    scanf("%d", &decision);
                    switch (decision) {
                    case 1:
                        printf("\nEnter new surname\n");
                        editStr(temp->surname);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        printf("\nEnter new name\n");
                        editStr(temp->name);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        printf("\nEnter new patronymic\n");
                        editStr(temp->patronymic);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        printf("\nEnter new gender\n");
                        editStr(temp->gender);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        printf("\nEnter new day of birthday\n");
                        editInt(&temp->dateOfBirth.day);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        printf("\nEnter new month of birthday\n");
                        editInt(&temp->dateOfBirth.month);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        printf("\nEnter new year of birthday\n");
                        editInt(&temp->dateOfBirth.year);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        printf("\nEnter new height\n");
                        editInt(&temp->height);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        printf("\nEnter new weight\n");
                        editInt(&temp->weight);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        printf("\nEnter new city\n");
                        editStr(temp->city);
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        printf("\nEnter new interests\n");
                        editStr(temp->interests);
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        printf("\nEnter new bad habits\n");
                        editStr(temp->badHabits);
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        printf("\nEnter new selfinfo\n");
                        editStr(temp->textMyself);
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        printf("\nEnter new preferred min age\n");
                        editInt(&temp->prefAgeMin);
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        printf("\nEnter new preferred max age\n");
                        editInt(&temp->prefAgeMax);
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        printf("\nEnter new preferred bad habits\n");
                        editStr(temp->prefBadHab);
                        break;
                    default:
                        myFree(&temp);
                        return;
                    }
                    system("cls");
                }
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ставлю на то что после предыдущего ввода `scanf`'ом в буфере остался `'\n'`... и да, [mcve] в студию

Comment: Скорее всего, что-то делаете не так. Приведите код вместо общих рассуждений - словом, приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: а как очистить буфер после scanf'а?

Comment: @kravien, несколько вариантов, например, читать всё `fgets`'ом, а прочитанную строку парсить `sscanf`'ом... или включить `\n` в форматную строку `scanf`'а...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло:

```
while (char c = getchar() != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Answer (score 1):

Все понятно.

После чтения `scanf` в буфере остается, как минимум, символ перехода на новую строку, который и считывается, как отдельная (пустая) строка.

Сбрасывайте после чтения `scanf` строку до конца - да хоть просто чтением в никуда до символа `\n`:

```
while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
```